# Compact Embeddings

Tags: compactness, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open with no assumptions on the boundary $\partial\Omega$. Show that $H^{k+1}_0(\Omega)$ is compactly embedded in $W^{k,2}(\Omega)$.

Show that if $\Omega$ is bounded, then $L^2(\Omega)$ is compactly embedded in $H^{−1}(\Omega)$

By Wikipedia,(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_embedding) I know I have to satisfy two conditions. I'd appreciate a full, clear answer on how to do these two exercises.

Comment: Do you know that $H_0^1(\Omega)$ is compactly embedded in $L^2(\Omega)$?

Comment: Yes. I just read that the inclusion you mentioned is compact

Comment: I still don't see how I can generalize it for the first problem

Comment: If the sequence $u$ is bounded in $H_0^{k+1}$, the sequence of $k$-th derivatives $D^k u$ is bounded in $H_0^1$, hence, a subsequence converges in $L^2$.

Comment: @gerw Can you explain?